# VBA: ROW copy and delete

Tags: excel, vba

I need a code that can deletethe entire row from "Sheet1", but copy column "B, C, D , E and G" to "Sheet2".
The data must be pasted in the next available row, from the bottom.

I assume it should be after " If Not aCell Is Nothing Then", but I can't figure out how to code it.

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim strSearch As String
Dim aCell As Range

On Error GoTo Err

'~~> Hvilket ark hvor ID skal søges efter
Set ws = Sheets("LS - Huawei")

With ws
    '~~> Hvor value skal findes og søges efter
    strSearch = Textbox1.Value

    '~~> Kolonne A er (1)
    '~~> xlWhole bruges til at finde det komplette match
    '~~> xlPart til et part match
    Set aCell = .Columns(1).Find(What:=strSearch, LookIn:=xlValues, _
    LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
    MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

    '~~> ser om der er fundet et match
    If Not aCell Is Nothing Then
        '~~> Flytter række fra LS - Huawei og indsætter den i Personalesalg  på næste ledige række.

    Else '<~~ Hvis ID ikke er fundet
        MsgBox "ID kan ikke findes"
    End If
End With

Exit Sub
Err: MsgBox Err.Description 
End Sub
```

Comment: Please do not post image of your code, edit your question and copy/paste the code in codeblock.

Comment: @RaymondWu I hope everything is in order now.

Answer (score 0):

Since you did not elaborate on the pasting of value in Sheet2. This will copy and paste the value of `aCell`'s Column B,C,D,E and G (skipping F) to Sheet2's Column B, C, D, E and G next available row.

And lastly it will delete `aCell`'s row.

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()        
        Dim ws As Worksheet
        Dim strSearch As String
        Dim aCell As Range
                
        On Error GoTo Err
        
        '~~> Hvilket ark hvor ID skal søges efter
        Set ws = Sheets("LS - Huawei")
        
        With ws
            '~~> Hvor value skal findes og søges efter
            strSearch = Textbox1.Value
            
            '~~> Kolonne A er (1)
            '~~> xlWhole bruges til at finde det komplette match
            '~~> xlPart til et part match
            Set aCell = .Columns(1).Find(What:=strSearch, LookIn:=xlValues, _
            LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
            MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
        
            '~~> ser om der er fundet et match
            If Not aCell Is Nothing Then
                '~~> Flytter række fra LS - Huawei og indsætter den i Personalesalg  på næste ledige række.
                Dim pasteWSLastRow As Long
                pasteNewRow = Sheet2.Range("C" & Sheet2.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
                
                Sheet2.Range("C" & pasteNewRow & ":E" & pasteNewRow).Value = .Range("C" & aCell.Row & ":E" & aCell.Row).Value
                Sheet2.Range("G" & pasteNewRow).Value = .Range("G" & aCell.Row).Value
                
                .Rows(aCell.Row).Delete
            Else '<~~ Hvis ID ikke er fundet
                MsgBox "ID kan ikke findes"
            End If
        End With
    
    Exit Sub
Err:   MsgBox Err.Description
    End Sub
```

Please specify how you want the values to be pasted in Sheet2 if the destination is incorrect.

Comment: Hi Raymond,

Thank you!

The values pasted in sheet2 are correct. Trying to run it gives me the error "Object required".

How do I go about  fixing this? I've read up on the error, but I can't seem to find the cause.

Comment: @Spoddi Which line did you get the error? Maybe instead of just `Sheet2`, change to `ThisWorkbook.Sheet2` or assign a variable to it like how you did to `ws`

Answer (score 0):

### Copy Cell Values, Delete Row

- Adjust the values in the constants section.
- Remove or out-comment the `Debug.Print` lines when done testing.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub VBALookup()
    
    Const sName As String = "LS - Huawei"
    Const sFirst As String = "A2"
    Const sColsList As String = "B,C,D,E,G"
    
    Const dName As String = "Personalesalg"
    Const dFirst As String = "A2"

    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    
    Dim Criteria As String: Criteria = TextBox1.Value
    
    ' Create a reference to the Source Lookup (Column) Range.
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = wb.Worksheets(sName)
    Dim sfCell As Range: Set sfCell = sws.Range(sFirst)
    Dim slCell As Range
    Set slCell = sfCell.Resize(sws.Rows.Count - sfCell.Row + 1) _
        .Find("*", , xlFormulas, , , xlPrevious)
    If slCell Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Empty source column."
        Exit Sub
    End If
    Dim slrg As Range: Set slrg = sws.Range(sfCell, slCell)
    Debug.Print "Source Lookup Range:          " & slrg.Address
    
    ' Create a reference to the Source (Entire) Row Range.
    Dim rIndex As Variant: rIndex = Application.Match(Criteria, slrg, 0)
    If IsError(rIndex) Then
        MsgBox "ID kan ikke findes"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    Dim srrg As Range: Set srrg = slrg.Cells(rIndex).EntireRow
    Debug.Print "Source (Entire) Row Range:    " & srrg.Address
    
    ' Create a reference to the Source (Entire) Columns Range.
    Dim sCols() As String: sCols = Split(sColsList, ",")
    Dim nUpper As Long: nUpper = UBound(sCols)
    Dim scrg As Range
    Dim n As Long
    For n = 0 To UBound(sCols)
        If scrg Is Nothing Then
            Set scrg = sws.Columns(sCols(n))
        Else
            Set scrg = Union(scrg, sws.Columns(sCols(n)))
        End If
    Next n
    Debug.Print "Source (Entire) Column Range: " & scrg.Address
    
    ' Create a reference to the Source (Row) Range.
    Dim srg As Range: Set srg = Intersect(srrg, scrg)
    Debug.Print "Source Row Range:             " & srg.Address
    
    ' Define the Destination Array.
    Dim cCount As Long: cCount = srg.Cells.Count
    Dim dData As Variant: ReDim dData(1 To 1, 1 To cCount)
    
    ' Write the values from the Source (Row) Range to the Destination Array.
    Dim sCell As Range
    Dim c As Long
    For Each sCell In srg.Cells
        c = c + 1
        dData(1, c) = sCell.Value
    Next sCell
    
    ' Create a reference to the Destination First Cell Range.
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = wb.Worksheets(dName)
    Dim difCell As Range: Set difCell = dws.Range(dFirst)
    Dim dCell As Range
    Set dCell = difCell.Resize(dws.Rows.Count - difCell.Row + 1) _
        .Find("*", , xlFormulas, , , xlPrevious)
    Dim dfCell As Range
    If dCell Is Nothing Then
        Set dfCell = difCell
    Else
        Set dfCell = dCell.Offset(1)
    End If
    
    ' Create a reference to the Destination Range.
    Dim drg As Range: Set drg = dfCell.Resize(, cCount)
    Debug.Print "Destination Range:            " & drg.Address
    
    ' Write the values from the Destination Array to the Destination Range.
    drg.Value = dData
    
    ' Delete the entire row i.e. Source (Entire) Row Range.
    srrg.Delete
    
    MsgBox "Done."

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi!

I have adjusted the values in the constant section - when I try to run the command button I get the error "Invalid inside procedure".  
"Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()" is highlighted with yellow.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Okay - I've gotten it to work, but it will only copy the information, if the A column is "Test". Dim Criteria As String: Criteria = "Test" ' TextBox1.Value How do I get around this with your code?

Comment: Just remove the `"Test ' "` as I did.

Comment: You are right - I made a mistake when I tried to do that. Thank you very much!

I'd like to enter an employee number (M-number). in TextBox2 - this should be pasted into the destination sheet, Personalesalg in column H.

Is it something you can help me with?

Comment: I have tried the methods i'm aware of, but your code is a bit more advanced than my VBA knowledge.

I'd definitely appreciate help with this last thing - if and when you have time.

Comment: Do you have time to help me out? Would be very much appreciated.